# Divisão de Telas usando Android + Unity

Tags: android, android-layout, unity3d

Gente, boa tarde.

Estou com um projeto no qual eu preciso pegar a visão de um determinado objeto em 4 pontos diferentes e posicioná-las a fim de ficar algo parecido com esse vídeo:https://www.youtube.com/embed/yZDGQmwM3jE

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu posso fazer isso? Tem como fazer dentro do próprio Unity? Ou devo pegar meu projeto do Unity e dar um jeito de adaptar para o Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Não consigo ver o video mas pela descrição imagino que você esteja tentando criar 4 viewports com visões de pontos diferentes de seu objeto.

Se for isso é bem fácil de reslver, basta ajustar a reta de cada uma das 4 cameras com valores normalizados.

Para testar crire um GameObject vazio e 4 cameras dentro dele, um script para manipular estas cameras e ajuste a reta delas, algo tipo:

```
public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera[] cameras;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        cameras[0].rect = new Rect( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f );
        cameras[1].rect = new Rect( 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f );
        cameras[2].rect = new Rect( 0.0f, 0.5f , 0.5f, 1.0f );
        cameras[3].rect = new Rect( 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    }
}
```

Arraste este script para o GameObject pai das cameras.

Inclua um objeto na cena e posicione as cameras conforme você quer que estejam mostrando seu objeto (em 4 diferentes posições e angulos).

Rode o game e verifique se é +- isso ;)

Comment: Acabei resolvendo isso de forma diferente, quadrupliquei a imagem e ajustei-as para simular o vídeo.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y60mfBvXCj8 Um vídeo similar ao que postei.